# In Visual Studio, I am making a struct in a header file and when i initalize it i get an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I keep on getting these 5 errors repeated many times after building. can someone help? all of the errors are from the cpp file.
code is below

> 1. C3927   '->': trailing return type is not allowed after a non-function declarator
> 2. C3613     missing return type after '->' ('int' assumed)
> 3. C2371     'Ttypes': redefinition; different basic types
> 4. C4430     missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> 5. C2440     'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [8]' to 'int'
> 6. C2146     syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'START'

each of these are repeated many times. for the sixth one START is changed to each variable name. here is the code.

file.h:

```
        struct TTYPES
        {
            std::string START;
            std::string CHAR;
            std::string NUM;
            std::string WHITESPACE;
            std::string OPERATOR;
            std::string PARENTHESIS;
            std::string BRACKETS;
            std::string END;

            // command types
            Type FUNC;
        } Ttypes;
```

file.cpp:

```
std::string Ttypes.START       = "0START;";
std::string Ttypes.CHAR        = "1CHAR;QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
std::string Ttypes.NUM         = "1NUM;1234567890";
std::string Ttypes.WHITESPACE  = "1WHITESPACE;\n\t\v ";
std::string Ttypes.OPERATOR    = "0OPERATOR;+-*/";
std::string Ttypes.PARENTHESIS = "0PARENTHESIS;()";
std::string Ttypes.BRACKETS    = "0BRACKETS;[]";
std::string Ttypes.END         = "0END;";
```

can anyone figure out why these errors are being created?

Comment: You posted two disjoint sets of code.  Please post a single [mcve].  We have no idea how the first set of code is used in the second set of code (no `#include`, no functions defined, etc.)

Comment: have you, maybe figured it out, eventually? I would be interested in what was the cause of the first error you mentioned.